# Making a nav bar using bootstrap and the dropdown button wont work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the code any ideas as to why the drop down button is not working, i have been watching tutorials on the internet and searching here for solutions but to no avail, its probably me being stupid but please help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Squad Builder.net</a>


        </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Information</a>
                    </li>

            </div>
    </div>  

  </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because you haven't added any items *to* the dropdown to be displayed when you click it.**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8qq8w0vb/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Squad Builder.net</a>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Information <span class="caret"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, don't forget to add the span with the caret class to indicate it's a dropdown.

Comment: thanks man i knew it was something stupid :/ i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

i hope that i got what you want

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                 <!--first u need to add the list tag <li>-->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <!--then add the first level link with toggle class see bootstrap docs-->
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Information 
                        <!--this is to display the small arrow u can change it to what ever u want-->
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <!--here are the second level links-->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                    </li>
                <!--u forgot to close the first <ul>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
```